# Why is `booleanValue` different from `booleanValue === true`?

Tags: typescript

Adding `=== true` to the expression in the code below breaks TypeScript's type inference. I know that pretty much all style guides recommend not adding `=== true`, but I would like to know **why** the two expressions are different.

Can anybody explain this?

```js
function someFunction(element: HTMLElement | null) {
  const isAllowed = element !== null;

  if (isAllowed) {
    // Here, the TypeScript compiler is able to infer that element isn't null...
    thisFunctionRequiresAnElement(element);
  }

  if (isAllowed === true) {
    // ... but here, it cannot. Why?
    thisFunctionRequiresAnElement(element);
  }
}

function thisFunctionRequiresAnElement(element: HTMLElement) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Link to [TypeScript Playground with the code snippet above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgwBsNMwoAuRACQBUBZAGQFFTypEAfRMEY4gEpEAbwBQiRBATJOMZAEEBcAO4YAJogC8iEmQwVEAQi06+AgNxiJiGMEQF5S4qo3DxkyQHovtDACcMABpEKAALDEQ6AE8ABwwAZQh-GFjOaTRYmFJ-W2REAEMAI1JQuFswYADQsILOPQ48sAByTnNiADoum0lw+RxIWAQAJQwARxAYQMUwNn0KInYDKEErSQBfa0k7BydlNU1THSh-EAx3HsQfRC6OxCKQTgjAkJh0grAwOCg7gHUw6IAfkufWQAzwI3Gk2mClmSwWDWWqxsm02YlAg3wNX6uCGYFGEymGBmcw4i3mVFojFY8JWohs0jAqFIHRcAHNyRxkZsgA).

Comment: The difference is that `=== true` checks against the true value only, whereas not adding the comparison checks for a 'truthy' (not null, undefined, 0, empty string, and maybe something I missed) value

Comment: @pascalpuetz does that make any difference here ? Typescript already knows that the value is a boolean. So it is either true or false. And in both if condition, OP is checking the same thing

Comment: My guess would be that this goes deeper. It's quite remarkable that TS is able to infer the existence of the element in the first case! I'd call this something like an "indirect inference". I can only imagine that in the background, only a limited number of these logical connections can be kept, as their number would probably grow like O(n!), where n is the number of "abstractions" (here, n seems to be one). Since the second case effectively checks the value of a newly generated boolean from the comparison, the abstraction level would go up (n=2), and that just seems to be too much?!

Comment: Watch Anders Hejlsberg explain this thing: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/V5OnAN63vls?t=3108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [TS 4.4 "feature"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730).

The `isAllowed` variable acts like a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). This means `isAllowed` holds the information that `element` is not `null`.

By adding a `=== true` this removes the predicate. You're in fact creating a new boolean from a `boolean` expression.

I don't know if we can consider this a bug or a feature.

[Playground with TS < 4.4 with both conditions with errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgwBsNMwoAuRACQBUBZAGQFFTypEAfRMEY4gEpEAbwBQiRBATJOMZAEEBcAO4YAJogC8iEmQwVEAQi06+AgNxiJiGMEQF5S4qo3DxkyQHovtDACcMABpEKAALDEQ6AE8ABwwAZQh-GFjOaTRYmFJ-W2REAEMAI1JQuFswYADQsILOPQ48sAByTnNiADoum0lw+RxIWAQAJQwARxAYQMUwNn0KInYDKEErSQBfa0k7BydlNU1THSh-EAx3HsQfRC6OxCKQTgjAkJh0grAwOCg7gHUw6IAfkufWQAzwI3Gk2mClmSwWDWWqxsm02YlAg3wNX6uCGYFGEymGBmcw4i3mVFojFY8JWohs0jAqFIHRcAHNyRxkZsgA)

---

Edit:

The comment by Anders Hejlsberg (TS creator) nails it :

> Narrowing through indirect references occurs only when the conditional
> expression or discriminant property access is declared in a const
> variable declaration with no type annotation, and the reference being
> narrowed is a const variable, a readonly property, or a parameter for
> which there are no assignments in the function body.

Comment: your playground link seems to be incomplete...

Comment: Reigler I wonder if my comment from above regarding performance is the correct reason for this not being more powerful than it is? Do you know the internals well enough to answer that?

Comment: @NoBullsh1t Probably not, I'd guess it's a feature. Making a "real" boolean drops the predicate.

Comment: @NoBullsh1t please see my edit with the quote of Hejlsberg

Comment: I read, I do not fully comprehend. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgwBsNMwoAuRACQBUBZAGQFFTypEAfRMEY4gEpEAbwBQiRBATJOMZAEEBcAO4YAJogC8iEmQwVEAQi06+AgNxiJUmZ1IA3EnRVwlxVRu2J57z5tMdKAAnEAwLRAB6SNswWQA6RABJZERSZFSoAAsAQ05gGCc0jCdiZGtJGGBEAkdnVz81dWFxSUloxAB1XM51GE0kxAAjYIwcgGsAfhtJbPkcSFgEACUMAEcQGFHFMDZ9CiJ2AyhBK0kAX2tQRfxEOeQFvBX1ze2FXaODvQ5qemY9jgtGzSOJwUjxDwAc0O+xOVkuQA)

Comment: @NoBullsh1t In your example it's not about the level (not the union in the example) but you're creating a new boolean that has no info about the type !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246480/discussion-between-nobullsh1t-and-matthieu-riegler).